# Responsive header with side nav and hero image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a project that has a header and navigation. Like so:
[image: diagram]

I'm having a tough time with the layout. I can put it together just fine, but I'm shaky with the responsiveness (is that a word?). Right now, the pseudo code is something like:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 960px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul><li>...</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

I was also considering using a background-image for the image and then creating strict breakpoints, but there has to be a better way.

I'm hoping to have the nav scrunch up to reflect the new height/width of the image, depending on the width of the viewport. When it's too thin to facilitate this, it will change to a mobile-friendly view (which is no problem for me).

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I just edited the question to explain better.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)